# Best way to isolate React Context Providers based on user permissions?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, user-controls, react-router-v4, react-context

I'm building a React application, which will end up very big.  E-commerce, different users, different permissions, advertisements, lots of sensitive data flowing around, etc.

I plan on using the context Provider to help with my state management.  One such facet I'm looking into is User Permissions in general.  Examples being, Admin Users has the ability to alter the permissions of a regular user, Admin Users have access to an Admin Dashboard, Admin Users have the ability to refund sales and create products, etc.

Is there a best way to use Context Provider to set up these permissions?  What worries me is that through most set-ups, most users with React Dev Tools will be able to open them and alter the state within to achieve whichever permissions they like.  Is this unavoidable?